# Rails 3 Sunspot Limit Objects to be indexed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I am using Rails 3 sunspot solr.
I want to restrict Objects to be indexed.
e.g. Index Posts where ids ranges from 1..1000. After that it should not be index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found my answer

```
searchable :if => :id_less_than_1000? do
...
end
def id_less_than_1000?
  self.id < Post.maximum(:id)
end
```